# Where to store the loading/error state with Vue.JS/Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm currently learning Vue.js, having worked with React before. Everything's going well so far, but I'm encountering a code design problem and can't find a precise answer on Google.

As a learning project, I'm developing a frontend for the Hacker News API. To manage my state, I'm using Vuex.

This is what my component looks like:

```
// Component.vue
<template lang="pug">
div(v-if="item.loading")
  span.story-loading Loading story...

div(v-else-if="item.error")
  span.story-error Something went wrong while fetching this story.

div(v-else)
  a.story-link(:href="item.url") {{item.title}}
  span.story-metadata
    | {{item.score}} points by {{item.by}} | {{item.descendants}} comments
</template>
```

My question is: **where should I handle the loading state and potential error states of my components?**

I've got two solutions.

The first one would be to let my component handle it, and just leave the fetching itself to Vuex, as follows:

```
// store.js
mutations: {
  createItem(state, data) {
    state.items = { ...state.items, [data.id]: data };
  }
},
actions: {
  getItem({ commit }, id) {
    return fetchItem(id).then(data => commit("createItem", data));
  }
}

// Component.vue
data() {
  return {
    loading: false,
    error: false
  };
},
created() {
  this.loading = true;
  this.getItem(this.id)
    .then(() => {
      this.loading = false;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.error = true;
    });
}
```

The other solution would be to let Vuex manage it, as follows:

```
// store.js
mutations: {
  fetchItemPending(state, id) {
    state.items = { ...state.items, [id]: { loading: true } };
  },
  fetchItemComplete(state, id) {
    state.items = { ...state.items, [id]: { loading: false } };
  },
  createItem(state, data) {
    state.items = { ...state.items, [data.id]: data };
  },
  erroredItem(state, id) {
    state.items = { ...state.items, [id]: { error: true } };
  }
},
actions: {
  getItem({ commit }, id) {
    commit("fetchItemPending", id);
    fetchItem(id)
      .then(data => {
        commit("fetchItemComplete", id);
        commit("createItem", data);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        commit("fetchItemComplete", id);
        commit("erroredItem", id);
      });
  }
}

// Component.vue (note how we don't manage anything related to the loading or errors anymore)
created() {
  this.getItem(this.id);
}
```

I like the first solution style, but I feel like the component shouldn't have to handle the state.

The second solution lets Vuex handle all the state. But all these mutations only to manage the loading and error state feel weird.

Which one would be the closest to the Vue.js/Vuex philosophy? Or should I do it completely differently?

**TL;DR: Where should I manage my loading and error state?**

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert, but I share my error state handling system.

One of my store action method looks like this:

```
  actions: {
      loadClasses ({ commit }) {
        console.debug("actions loadClasses; is called!");
        return rootActions.getter('/api/m/class/getall')
          .then(r => {
            if(r && r.result) {
              let classes = r.result;
              commit('SET_CLASSES', classes);
            } else {
              console.error("actions loadClasses; error occours during loading the classes! Error: " + JSON.stringify(r.error));
            }
            return r;
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error("actions loadClasses; error occours during loading the classes! Error: " + error);
            throw error;
          });
      },
```

- rootActions is an axios
- My rest api respond is like: `{result:
  "asdasdasd", error: NULL}` or `{result: NULL, error: "E.G.: servererror"}`

What is the benefit of this?

In the components I can get the result or the error:

```
loadClasses: function() {
  console.debug("classmanager-container loading classes..");
  return this.$store.dispatch('classes/loadClasses')
    .then(r => {
      if(r && r.result) {
        this.classes = this.$store.getters['classes/classesNameId'];
      } else {
        this.showErrorAlert(this.$i18n.t('basic.loaderror'));
      }
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.showErrorAlert(this.$i18n.t('basic.loaderror'));
    })
},
```

- The `showErrorAlert` function will inform the user via alert.

For example, when I save a new class, the system is the same, and I make an alert of success If the `r.result` is not null. :)

**+1 benefit**: you can "force" the async ajax call into sequence. example:

```
loadUsers: function() {
  console.debug("classmanager-container loading users..");
  return this.$store.dispatch('users/loadsers')
    .then(r => {
      if(r && r.result) {
        this.users = this.$store.getters['users/usersNameId'];
        return this.loadClasses();
      } else {
        this.showErrorAlert(this.$i18n.t('basic.loaderror'));
      }
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.showErrorAlert(this.$i18n.t('basic.loaderror'));
    })
},
```

that way, the `loadClasses` method runs only if the users loaded well.